# Why did the cloned Xenomorphs kill one of their own?

Tags: alien-franchise, xenomorph, alien-resurrection-1997

Why did the cloned Xenomorphs kill one of their own in order to escape their holding cells when they could spit acid? Wouldn't they have been able to just spit at the ground, thus melting it?

It just seems illogical given these creatures' survival-driven instinct. So what are your thoughts on this?

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14Mf_nTyWBc) is what I meant, the spitting happens at around 0:50.

I also noticed that Drones from the first 2 movies were also able to spit acid according to [this](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Drone) wiki article.

Comment: Well, *can* they spit their acidic blood?

Comment: Well, not their blood, but they were definitely able to spit acid. Whether the acidity of their spit is equally as strong as that of their blood, I have no clue.

Comment: Did they do that in *Resurrection*? If there's clear evidence they can, it might be worth adding that to the question. I don't recall them being able to spit acid in any of the first 3 films, but I admittedly don't have the best recollection of the 4th.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added a link that shows what I mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FATHER is continually monitoring the structural integrity of the holding cage. Spitting acid would have weakened the bars, but not before the handlers were able to use the nitrogen gas button to incapacitate the xenomorphs. By ripping one of their number apart, they were able to spread acid all around them (and cover themselves in it), hastening their escape.

> “There is serious structural damage to animal holding facility number
>   zero, zero, one. There is serious structural damage to animal holding
>   facility number zero, zero, one. The damage is sufficient to breach
>   the security of animal holding facility number zero, zero, one. There
>   is serious structural damage to animal holding facility number—”

Note that the [official novelisation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Alien-Resurrection-Official-Movie-Novelization/dp/1783296739) mentions that the Alien that was killed was suffering from a bout of individualism. Despite being able to see the sense of killing itself for the greater good, it was also reluctant to allow this to happen.

> The first warrior turned to his closer brother, transmitted
>   information to him. The second warrior absorbed the information. He
>   stopped pacing. Together, the two looked back at the third. The
>   smaller one understood their objective, their reasons, the whole new
>   concept. He even agreed with it. However, he was also burdened with
>   his own individuality, and edged back against the wall of the cave
>   nervously.

Comment: This makes sense. That's why the alien seemed to "quarrel" with it's kin before being torn apart. Poor fella.

Comment: @LeonidasFett - That's what you get for being the runt of the litter :-)